# React + Karma : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined\nat

Tags: reactjs, karma-jasmine

Following is my spec file for the unit testing of the react component (**helloworld.spec.js**):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'; // ES6
import {HelloWorld} from './helloworld';

describe("HelloWorld Test",function(){

it("check header", function(){
    var component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
                    <HelloWorld />
                    );
    var eventRow = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(
        component, 'h1'
        );
    expect(eventRow.getDOMNode().textContent)
    .toEqual("template header");
  });
});
```

And here is the **helloworld.js**:

```
import React from 'react';

export class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

I have setup karma and jasmine for the unit testing and getting the error :

**{
    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined\nat src/components/hello-world/helloworld.spec.js:3:14\n\nReferenceError: require is not defined\n    at src/components/hello-world/helloworld.spec.js:3:14",
    "str": "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined\nat src/components/hello-world/helloworld.spec.js:3:14\n\nReferenceError: require
 is not defined\n    at src/components/hello-world/helloworld.spec.js:3:14"
  }**

But I don't see require in the code so how come it's not defined.
Any leads for where the issue could be, probably a config one?

Comment: 1. Can you please share export statement of ./eventticketcontainer,
2. Please check your package.json and config.js for any inclusion of requireJS.

Comment: I have tried it out with another basic component, still it gives the 'require' error. Updated the code snippet. Can you have a look now @SanchitGoel

Answer (score 0):

It actually means you've to define require. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) is the link to stackoverflow

> This is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript

Comment: But I haven't used require() anywhere in my event-ticket.spec.js file. Where is it coming from? Can you explain why do I need to do that?